# Is a positively homogeneous convex function lower semi-continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Here the definition of positively homogeneous function $f$ is
\begin{equation}
f(\lambda x) = \lambda f(x), \quad \lambda \ge 0,
\end{equation}
and $f$ is defined on linear space $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I think this statement could not be held, but I could not find any counter example.

Comment: Any discontinuous functional on an infinite-dimensional normed linear space will be an example of such a function.

Comment: I got it. But if the function is defined on a finite-dimensional linear space $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Then that assumption should really be in your question. :-)

Comment: Can $f$ take the value $\infty$? Or are you assuming finite values?

Comment: Sorry, it is my carelessness. And $f$ could take value $\infty$. I do not assume finite values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to [0,\infty]$ by
$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0,& x \in (-\infty,0)^2 \cup \{(0,0)\}\\
\infty,& \text{otherwise}  \end{cases}$.

Then let $x_n = (-{1 \over n},-1)$, we have $f(x_n) = 0$, $\liminf_n f(x_n) < f(\lim_n x_n) = \infty$.

Hence $f$ is convex but not lsc.

Comment: Thank you. And I also found a theorem about this in ``Convex Analysis'', Theorem 9.7. (Btw, I have seen your profile and then try to find it in this book. So thank you once again.)

Comment: Glad to be able to help :-).